# LazyEnum with validation

Tags: python, python-3.x, object-oriented, enum, meta-programming

### **Motivation**

In the standard Python library `enum`, a subclass of `Enum` would create all its members upon class creation. This can be a huge waste of time and memory, especially if the class contains lots of members but only a fraction of them would ever get called.

As a practice project on metaclasses, I decided to implement a lazy version of `Enum`. This is not intended to be a full-fledged library, so I didn't implement most of the features in the standard `enum` library, just some basic functionalities.

In `LazyEnum`, a member would be created only when we ask to and it would be created only once. For example, let say `MyClass` is a subclass of `LazyEnum`. The first time we call `MyClass(1)` an object of type `MyClass` is created. Any subsequent call to `MyClass(1)` simply return the same object. Moreover, I want to put some validation on member creation, say we may only allow `n` to be a positive integer when calling `MyClass(n)`.

This idea is inspired by [Ethan Furman](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/88700/ethan-furman)'s reply to my [previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/241884/use-python-enum-to-implement-residue-ring-and-multiplicative-residue-group) here and also a discussion on Udemy with [Fred Baptiste](https://www.udemy.com/user/fredbaptiste/), who is the instructor of the [Python 3 Deep Dive](https://www.udemy.com/course/python-3-deep-dive-part-1/) series.

Before looking at the code, let me provide an example of how to use `LazyEnum`.

### **Example**

```
from lazyenum import LazyEnum

class Product(LazyEnum):
    def _validate_identifier_value(product_id):
        # special method used by metaclass for validation
        return isinstance(product_id, int) and (1001 <= product_id <= 9999)

    COMPANY_NAME = 'Our Example Company'

    def __init__(self, product_id, product_title):
        # no need to store 'product_id' as instance attribute
        self.product_title = product_title

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Product({self.product_id!r}, {self.product_title!r})'
```

Remark:

1. `LazyEnum` is created by a private metaclass `_LazyEnumMeta`.
2. The first non-self parameter of `__init__` is automatically grabbed by the metaclass and cached, so we don't need to set it as an instance attribute. If we write `self.product_id = product_id`, it would raise an error when we try to initialize a new member. This parameter is called the **identifier field** and its value is called the **identifier value**, which uniquely identify each member.
3. The metaclass would look for a method named `_validate_identifier_value` and use it for validation. It can be defined as a static method or a class method, but if we define it as a class method, we would need to decorate it with `@classmethod`. Here we just define it as a static method.

Let us see some example outputs. First, we can initialize a member as usual and call it by its identifier value.

```
>>> prod1 = Product(1001, 'Our Nice First Product')
>>> Product(1001)
Product(1001, 'Our Nice First Product')
>>> prod1 is Product(1001)
True
```

We can get the identifier value by using `.identifier_field` or directly calling the instance attribute (`.product_id` in this case). The `.identifier_field` would give us a nametuple called `Identifier`, whose first entry is the attribute name and the second entry is the value.

```
>>> prod1.identifier_field
Identifier(field_name='product_id', value=1001)
>>> prod1.product_id
1001
```

Error would be raised if we attempt to create a new member with an existing identifier value. Of course, the same thing would happen if we use an invalid identifier value.

```
>>> Product(1001, 'This Is Still The First Product')
ValueError: Member with identifier value 1001 already exists. Cannont pass additional arguments ('This Is Still The First Product',) or {}.
>>> Product(1, 'Product With Invaild ID')
ValueError: Identifier field 'product_id' has invalid value 1.
```

In the regular `Enum`, you can set aliases to a member. Right now we didn't set any alias, but we can do so using dot notation and see all aliases of a member using `.all_aliases`. We can also simultaneously create a new member and set an alias to it.

```
>>> prod1.all_aliases
[]
>>> Product.product_one = prod1
>>> Product.first_product = Product.product_one
>>> prod1.all_aliases
['product_one', 'first_product']
>>> 
>>> Product.product_two = Product(1002, 'The Amazing Second Product')
>>> Product.product_two
Product(1002, 'The Amazing Second Product')
>>> Product(1002).all_aliases
['product_two']
```

But be careful, we may accidentally overwrite other class attributes.

```
>>> Product.COMPANY_NAME
'Our Example Company'
>>> Product.COMPANY_NAME = prod1
>>> prod1.all_aliases
['product_one', 'first_product', 'COMPANY_NAME']
>>> Product.COMPANY_NAME
Product(1001, 'Our Nice First Product')
>>> 
>>> Product.COMPANY_NAME = 'Our Example Company'
>>> prod1.all_aliases
['product_one', 'first_product']
```

We can change instance attributes that are not the identifier field. Attempting to change the identifier field would raise an error.

```
>>> prod1.product_title = 'First Product With New Name'
>>> prod1
Product(1001, 'First Product With New Name')
>>> prod1.product_id = 2001
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

We can iterate over the class members.

```
>>> Product(1003, 'Even More Amazing Third Product')
Product(1003, 'Even More Amazing Third Product')
>>> for prod in Product: print(prod)
Product(1001, 'First Product With New Name')
Product(1002, 'The Amazing Second Product')
Product(1003, 'Even More Amazing Third Product')
>>> len(Product)
3
```

Finally, the class has properties `.identifier_value_map` and `.alias_to_member_map`, which help inspect all members. Note that we didn't set any alias to `Product(1003)`.

```
>>> Product.identifier_value_map
mappingproxy({
    1001: Product(1001, 'First Product With New Name'),
    1002: Product(1002, 'The Amazing Second Product'),
    1003: Product(1003, 'Even More Amazing Third Product')
})
>>> Product.alias_to_member_map
mappingproxy(OrderedDict([
    ('product_one', Product(1001, 'First Product With New Name')),
    ('first_product', Product(1001, 'First Product With New Name')),
    ('product_two', Product(1002, 'The Amazing Second Product'))
]))
```

### **The Code**

Here is the code.

```
# lazyenum.py
from collections import namedtuple, OrderedDict
from types import MappingProxyType

_Identifier = namedtuple('Identifier', 'field_name value')

def _get_identifier_value(self):
    # use this function to monkey patch the class
    id_map = type(self)._object_id_to_value_map
    return id_map[id(self)]


class _LazyEnumMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, attrs):
        attrs['_object_id_to_value_map'] = {}
        attrs['_identifier_value_map'] = {}
        attrs['_alias_to_member_map'] = OrderedDict()
        cls = super().__new__(mcls, name, bases, attrs)

        # grab the first parameter name from the __init__ method
        # then inject it to the class as a read-only property
        id_name = cls.__init__.__code__.co_varnames[1]
        cls._identifier_field_name = id_name
        setattr(cls, id_name, property(_get_identifier_value))

        return cls

    def __call__(cls, value, *args, **kwargs):
        # rely on the class to provide the validation method
        if not cls._validate_identifier_value(value):
            raise ValueError(f'Identifier field {cls._identifier_field_name!r} '
                            f'has invalid value {value!r}.')

        # create a new memeber iff no existing member has the same identifier value
        if value not in cls._identifier_value_map:
            new_member = super().__call__(value, *args, **kwargs)
            cls._object_id_to_value_map[id(new_member)] = value
            cls._identifier_value_map[value] = new_member
        elif args or kwargs:
            raise ValueError(f'Member with identifier value {value!r} already exists. '
                            f'Cannont pass additional arguments {args} or {kwargs}.')

        return cls._identifier_value_map[value]

    def __contains__(cls, other):
        return other in cls._identifier_value_map.values()

    def __len__(cls):
        return len(cls._identifier_value_map)

    def __iter__(cls):
        yield from cls._identifier_value_map.values()

    def __setattr__(cls, attr_name, attr_value):
        if attr_name in cls._alias_to_member_map:
            del cls._alias_to_member_map[attr_name]

        # check if we are setting name to a class member
        if attr_value in cls:
            cls._alias_to_member_map[attr_name] = attr_value

        super().__setattr__(attr_name, attr_value)

    def __delattr__(cls, attr_name):
        if attr_name in cls._alias_to_member_map:
            del cls._alias_to_member_map[attr_name]

        super().__delattr__(attr_name)

    @property
    def identifier_value_map(cls):
        return MappingProxyType(cls._identifier_value_map)

    @property
    def alias_to_member_map(cls):
        return MappingProxyType(cls._alias_to_member_map)


class LazyEnum(metaclass=_LazyEnumMeta):
    # the first two methods serve as the defaults if a subclass didn't provide them
    # to avoid error when _LazyEnumMeta attempts to use those two methods
    def _validate_identifier_value(value):
        return True

    def __init__(self, identifier_value):
        pass

    @property
    def identifier_field(self):
        id_name = type(self)._identifier_field_name
        return _Identifier(id_name, getattr(self, id_name))

    @property
    def all_aliases(self):
        pairs = type(self)._alias_to_member_map.items()
        return [alias for alias, member in pairs if member is self]
```

### **Questions**

1.

The above code doesn't work well with dataclasses. If we write

```
from lazyenum import LazyEnum
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Product(LazyEnum):
    def _validate_identifier_value(product_id):
        return isinstance(product_id, int) and (1001 <= product_id <= 9999)

    product_id : int
    product_title : str
```

then type the following in the console:

```
>>> prod1 = Product(1001, 'First Product')
>>> prod1.product_id = 2001
>>> Product(2001)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'product_title'
>>> Product(1001)
Product(product_id=2001, product_title='First Product')
```

We can change the `product_id` but the member is still identified by the old value! How can I fix this?

2. Apart from the issue of dataclasses, is there any problem in the above code? Where can I make improvements?

Comment: I just skimmed over major part of question, so I could be wrong, but you might be interested in Singleton Pattern - and how it can be implemented in Python.

Comment: @kushj The class clearly has multiple instances and so the Singleton Pattern doesn't apply here. Additionally the OP is already using caching to only allow one instance per id.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I was just considering adding a lazy ability to Enum generation this last week!  I don't have enough experience with dataclasses to offer any aid with your question, but I will say that `LazyEnum` is not a great choice of name as your usage does not appear to be enum related (see [Python Enum -- when and where to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22594360/208880)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## High-level

1. `LazyEnum` should be separate from the underlying datatype.
   You should allow a similar interface like the following:

   ```py
   @dataclasses.dataclass
   class Product:
       id: int
       name: str

   class Products(metaclass=LazyEnumMeta, type=Product):
       pass

   Products(1001, 'foo')
   ```

   This can alleviate the following problem. If, however, you still run into this problem, it's because your using `Products` for something it shouldn't be used for.

   > But be careful, we may accidentally overwrite other class attributes.
2. You should allow the enum class to function similarly to how Python's does.

   ```py
   class Products(metaclass=LazyEnumMeta, type=Product):
       product_one = first_product = 1001
       product_two = 1002
   ```

   By only using the ID we can allow the the Product to not be constructed yet, but still define the mapping.
3. You should re-decide where the following exception is handled.

   > Member with identifier value {value!r} already exists.

   If you handle it on `Products` then you could theoretically allow people to create multiple `Product`s with different values that aren't in the enum.

   If you go Graipher's route then you're locking down `Product` when you may want to use it in two enums.

   It boils down to, where do you want the singleton `Product`s to be scoped?
4. I'm not a fan of having the `__call__` function as a `__getitem__`.

Here's a proof of concept for the above suggestions.

```py
import dataclasses
import inspect


class LazyEnumMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, attrs, type):
        _attrs = {}
        for key in list(attrs.keys()):
            if not (key.startswith('__') and key.endswith('__')):
                _attrs[key] = attrs.pop(key)

        attrs['_type'] = type
        arguments = inspect.signature(type).parameters.values()
        attrs['_id'] = next(iter(arguments)).name
        attrs['_attrs'] = _attrs
        attrs['_items'] = {}
        return super().__new__(mcls, name, bases, attrs)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        id = args[0] if args else kwargs[self._id]
        if id in self._items:
            return self._items[id]
        self._items[id] = item = self._type(*args, **kwargs)
        return item

    def __getitem__(self, id):
        return self._items[id]

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self._items[self._attrs[name]]


@dataclasses.dataclass
class Product:
    id: int
    name: str


class Products(metaclass=LazyEnumMeta, type=Product):
    FIRST = 1001


print(Products(id=1001, name='foo'))
print(Products[1001])
print(Products.FIRST)
```

## Granular

- Many of your names are long and needlessly use Hungarian notation `_object_id_to_value_map`. This can just be `_id_to_value` or `_by_ids`.

  You should notice that many of my names above are really short. `type`, `id`, `attrs`, `items`. You don't need long names, and when you do it's normally a good idea to refactor the code to prevent a god class.
- I'd much prefer to use `inspect` than the low level `cls.__init__.__code__.co_varnames[1]`.
- Your hanging indents are not 'correct'. You should change:

  > ```py
  > raise ValueError(f'Identifier field {cls._identifier_field_name!r} '
  >                 f'has invalid value {value!r}.')
  > ```

  To:

  ```py
  raise ValueError(f'Identifier field {cls._identifier_field_name!r} '
                   f'has invalid value {value!r}.')
  ```

  Alternately you can change your style and use:

  ```py
  raise ValueError(
      f'Identifier field {cls._identifier_field_name!r} '
      f'has invalid value {value!r}.'
  )
  ```
- I don't really see any gain from using `id(new_member)`. If anything it makes the code more annoying.
- I don't think exposing `identifier_value_map`, `alias_to_member_map`, `identifier_field` or `all_aliases` publicly are good design choices.

Comment: This is very informative and helpful advice. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

This right here is where I would start asking myself if this is a good idea or if there isn't a better way to achieve this:

> The first non-self parameter of `__init__` is automatically grabbed by
>   the metaclass and cached, so we don't need to set it as an instance
>   attribute. If we write self.product_id = product_id, it would raise an
>   error when we try to initialize a new member.

**This behavior is not obvious and it is not even properly documented, because your class does not have a `docstring`.**

Honestly, I don't quite get your enum story, either. At face value you just have a class that you can inherit from to make your class a singleton class depending on the arguments. For this I might use something like this:

```
class UniqueInstances:
    """Makes sure that each instance exists only once.
    Subclasses must implement __hash__ and __eq__ for this to work.
    Note that new instances are being created,
    but get discarded if they already exist.
    """
    __instances = {}
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        self = super().__new__(cls)
        self.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        return self.__instances.setdefault(self, self)

    def __hash__(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def __eq__(self, other):
        raise NotImplementedError

class Product(UniqueInstances):
    def __init__(self, product_id, name):
        self.product_id = product_id
        self.name = name

    def __hash__(self):
        return self.product_id

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.product_id == other.product_id

p1 = Product(1001, "Test")
p2 = Product(1001, "Foo")
print(p1 is p2, p1.name, p2.name)
# True Foo Foo
```

This is cheating a bit, because it *does* create a new instance, but it gets discarded if an equal instance already exists. If this still qualifies as *lazy*, I'm not sure.

It does however have the advantage that it is more obvious what happens, since you have to define `__hash__` and `__eq__` which is used to determine if an instance already exists.

Comment: Indeed your approach is much simpler. I didn't think of it. Thank you for the advice.